# How can I test my Grails webapp that has a subdomain for each client?

Tags: grails, testing, subdomain

I'm developing a Grails based webapp whose clients have your own subdomain. I take the client identification in my UrlMappings through the request URL and put that information oh the params object that will be consumed by the controllers. What's the best way and test types to grant the correctness of this scenario? I'm looking for platform independent solutions ( I don't want to edit /etc/hosts file on every machine that the tests will be run )

Answer (score 0):

We have a different way of achieving what we want (I for one would be interested in your UrlMappings solution).

I wrote a Groovy trait (something like `SubdomainAware`) and every controller `implements` it. That trait then has a getter (something like `getCustomer`) that sniffs the domain from the `request` object and fetches the customer domain object (so in my controllers I can do things like `User.findAllByCustomer(customer)`).

For functional and unit tests I allow an extra GET or POST parameter `forceDomain` which my `SubdomainAware` trait also looks for (though only in non-production environments) and which takes precedence over the actual request's domain. This allows me to simulate any subdomain I want in tests.

Comment: before this question my UrlMappings identified the subdomain. But, after some time I concluded that the best approach was to create a Filter before any action of any controler, that extract the subdomain and create a request attribute with that value, in such way that  any action can recover this value

Comment: Well how about doing something like this in your filter code: `if (Environment.current != Environment.PRODUCTION && params.mockDomain) { return params.mockDomain } else { /* real code for getting the subdomain */}` (under the assumption that the code has to return the subdomain used; you may need to adapt it). Then you can use the `mockDomain` GET or POST parameter in your tests to force the domain.